# Save data from two forms into same table in Winforms application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I have two Winforms where form 1 is used to enter data from first seven fields and other forms is used to enter for last three fields, where I have the table stored in SQL Server, but the problem is whenever I tried to save data in second forms it is getting stored in first row itself instead of the row where the first form is updating. Can anyone please help how to link these two forms and get them saved in the same row?

This is the code for saving the data in the second form and screenshots are attached:

```
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.ComponentModel;  
using System.Data;  
using System.Drawing;  
using System.Linq;  
using System.Text;  
using System.Threading.Tasks;  
using System.Windows.Forms;  
using System.Data.SqlClient;  

namespace Windows  
{  
    public partial class Form1 : Form  
    {  
        public Form1()  
        {  
            InitializeComponent();  
        }  
          
        private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
        {  
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);  
            SqlCommand cmd;  
            con.Open();  
            string s="insert into Student values(@p1,@p2,@p3)";  

            cmd = new SqlCommand(s,con);  
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1",rejectReason1ComboBox.Text);  
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2",rejectReason2ComboBox.Text);  
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3",rejectReason3ComboBox.Text);  
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;  

            int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  
            con.Close();  

            MessageBox.Show(i+ " Row(s) Inserted ");  
        }  
    }  
}
```

[image]

Comment: You simply want to get the input reasons from child form back to parent form?

Comment: Yes..I mean i want the child form data also to be saved in the parent form data source ( both the form has the data source of one table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add public properties in your `ChildForm` like this:

```
public string Reason1 {get; set;}
public string Reason2 {get; set;}

private void Combobox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Reason1 = (sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem.ToString();
}

private void ButtonOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     (sender as Button).DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
     // Or you can set this DialogResult property from Button's property window
}
```

And then in `ParentForm`, use the `ChildForm` like this

```
private void ButtonOpenChildForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (ChildForm form = new ChildForm())
            {
                if (form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    // Receive the Reasons here in any variable
                    string reason1 = form.Reason1;
                    string reason2 = form.Reason2;
                }
            }
        }
```