# Saving data from 2nd form to the same master table in Winform application

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, winforms, desktop-application

I have two winforms where form 1 is used to enter data from 44 fields and other forms is used to enter for three fields, where I have the table stored in SQL Server. Now when I try to save the last three fields I get an error

> Data field null error

this is because the "parent form data" is still not saved as it has to be saved after updating this child form , kindly guide me how to achieve this.

Code for saving data in second form:

```
private void Btnrejsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);

    SqlCommand cmd;
    con.Open();
    string s = "select * from IP_Spools where SpoolId = (@p4) insert into IP_Spools(RejectReason1,RejectReason2,RejectReason3) values(@p1,@p2,@p3)";

    cmd = new SqlCommand(s, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", rejectReason1ComboBox.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", rejectReason2ComboBox.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", rejectReason3ComboBox.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", IDtextbox.Text);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

image of the parent child form:
[image: Parent form in back , and child form in centre(front)]

this is my sql table:

[image: SQL TABLE(the field name of parent form is slightly change than in the other picture)]

Comment: Does this answers your question? [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65261828/save-data-from-two-forms-into-same-table-in-winforms-application)

Comment: yes that definitely helped me ...and i have accepted that as answer.

Comment: Don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Save data from two forms into same table in Winforms application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65261828/save-data-from-two-forms-into-same-table-in-winforms-application)